# Please verify my classification of the following singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, singularity

There are 2 functions of interest.

1.) $z^2e^{1/z}$

2.)$\dfrac{z}{\cos z}$

My attempt:

For (1.) we have singularities at $0$ and $\infty$.

For $z = 0$, the singularity is essential because $\lim_{z\rightarrow0} z^2e^{1/z}$ does not exist either as $\infty$ or some finite complex number

For $z = \infty, $ the singularity is removable as $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} z^2e^{1/z}$exist.

For (2.)

We have singularities at $z = \infty$ and $z = \frac{\pi}{2} \ +\ n\pi$

For $z = \infty$, the limit is a pole since $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{z}{cosz}$ is $\infty$

For $z = \frac{\pi}{2} \ +\ n\pi$, I am having some problem classifying this one, so any help or insight on this is appreciated.

So basically above is my attempt, if I made any mistake please do point it out for me. (and if possible provide an explanation)

Comment: What happens at those same points to $\frac{\cos z}z$?

Comment: for $\infty$ we will have 0 (cosine function are bounded), but the $\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$ we will have 0, so you trying to say that at this point is a pole singularity ?

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} z^2e^{1/z}=\lim_{u\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{u}}{u^2}=\infty$

Comment: Hint 2:  $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{ z}{\cos z}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{ 1}{u\cos(1/ u)}$ is undefined.

Comment: You're half right: $\cos$ is not bounded on the complex plane (no meromorphic function, other than constants, are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an holomorphic function $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with a zero in $z_0\in U$, then by using Taylor series, you can write in some open neighborhood of $z_0$, the function $f$ in the following form $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^nh(z),$$
where $n$ is the order of the zero $z_0$ and $h$ is holomorphic and non-zero in the chosen neighborhood. In particular note that $1/f(z)$ has a polus of order $n$ in $z_0$. In your case, the map $\cos z$ has a simple zero in $\pi/2$, since $\cos'(\pi/2)=\sin(\pi/2)\neq 0$, therefore $1/\cos z$ has a simple polus in $\pi/2$. By this last remark $z/\cos z$ has a simple polus in $\pi/2+n\pi$.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I dont quite understand your hint, perhaps you can elaborate a bit more ? Thank you

Comment: Yes :) One moment.

Comment: Done. Now I think it is simpler than before.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur pointed out by asking what happens to the same points for $\frac{\cos(z)}{z}$ .

Recall the definition : "A function $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=∞$ if $f(1/w)$ has a singularity at $w=0$ ." Since $\frac{\cos(z)}{z}$  has a singularity at $0$, what can you conclude about $\frac{z}{\cos(z)}$ ?

Comment: Why does $\frac{cos(z)}{z}$ has a pole at $\pi/2$, isn't the function define at $\pi /2$ ?

Comment: If $f=\frac{\cos(z)}{z}$ than $f(1/z)=z \cos (1/z)$.

Comment: @some1fromhell I meant it has a singularity at $0$.